# How to enable "extended_glob" in tcsh?

Tags: shell, wildcards, tcsh

I am looking to enable 'extended_glob' in tcsh shell and I tried these commands:

```
setopt extended_glob
shopt extended_glob
```

But , None of these worked.

Can anyone let me know a way to enable this in tcsh ?

Answer (score 2):

You might be confusing with `zsh`. `tcsh` has no *`extended_glob`* option. It's got a `globstar` option to add the `**/` and `***/` recursive glob operators of `zsh` (`globstar` being named after the same option in ksh93, though `ksh93` only added the `**/` variant), and `noglob` and `nonomatch` (those two copied by `zsh`, though `noglob` was initially from ksh I believe).

Options are just special variables in `tcsh` (note that it was also the case in `bash` (another shell with tcsh heritage) initially, until it changed to using a new `shopt` builtin), so to enable the option, you just set the variable:

```
set globstar
```

See `man tcsh` for details.